# Silex + Get translate strings from twig views

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I'm using the [TranslationServiceProvider](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/translation.html) from Silex (micro framework build based on symfony2 components). I now translate stuff in my view like this:

```
<h1>{{ 'psttoday'|trans }}</h1>
```

The `psttoday` is a tag that I use. The translations are stored in yml files. Is there a way that I can just set `{{ 'psttodo'|trans }}` and then run a script and write the tags to my database or some other file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to extract all strings that have the |trans filter attached?

Have a look at that answer:
[How to generate translation file (.po, .xliff, .yml,...) from a Symfony2/Silex project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139894/how-to-generate-translation-file-po-xliff-yml-from-a-symfony2-silex-p)

They propose:

- [xgettext](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/xgettext-Invocation.html)
- [POEdit](http://www.poedit.net/)

Also this Bundle has a extractor task:

- [JMSTranslationBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSTranslationBundle)